# return two tables with get_where

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working in php (codeigniter) and I wish to do this query

```
SELECT * FROM families, products WHERE family = "madison"
```

in this from

```
        $query = $this->db->get_where("families", array("family" => $key));
```

when I try

```
$query = $this->db->get_where("families", "products" array("family" => $key));
```

it returns errors.  is there anyway to do this?

edit:
    A Database Error Occurred

```
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'products' in 'where clause'

SELECT * FROM (`families`) WHERE `products` IS NULL LIMIT 1

Filename: /Users/Home/Sites/models/family_get.php

Line Number: 5
```

the problem is selecting the two tables

Comment: what is $key? in your code

Comment: $key would be "madison" or anyother string that call with.  Could be an int in some other cases.  Just i am not sure how to query two tables and return all the information

Comment: Echo `$this->db->last_query()` afterwards to print out what the resulting query is.  You will be able to see if it is creating an unexpected query.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'array' (T_ARRAY) in /Users/Home/Sites/application/models/family_get.php on line 5

Comment: you need a comma after `"products"`

Comment: get_where only takes 2 parameters and your syntax is wrong `"products" array("family" => $key)`

Answer (score 2):

This is not valid PHP syntax.

```
$query = $this->db->get_where("families", "products" array("family" => $key));
```

You should only pass two arguments to `get_where`. Something like this:

```
$query = $this->db->get_where("families, products", array("family" => $key));
```

Note that `get_where` takes four arguments, but you're not using offset/limit, so those *optional* arguments can be omitted.

Comment: get_where takes up to 4 parameters. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: get_where can take more than two arguments.......$query = $this->db->get_where('mytable', array('id' => $id), $limit, $offset);

Comment: thanks, so what would be and option to select or possibly join? I have never done a join

Comment: @VictorKilo, I forgot about offset/limit. Thanks, updated my answer based on your comment.

Comment: @Venkat, thanks for pointing that out. The last two arguments are irrelevant to this question, but updated for correctness anyway.

Comment: I am getting clause-is-ambiguous because I have two keys that are the same(families).  is there anyother way to achieve that get_where query?

Comment: @user1093111, that is a different question and has nothing to do with CodeIgniter. It's a (My)SQL question. Which of the two tables do you want to query? Both of them? If so, should it be `OR` or `AND`?

Comment: SELECT * FROM familes fam, products pro  WHERE fam.productname = 'hilton' AND pro.family = 'madison'

Comment: @user1093111, something like this? `get_where("families, products", array("families.productname" => 'hilton', "products.family" => 'madison'))`

Comment: @Mischa exactly like that. Thanks some much. It actually works this time.